# How to reduce latency for HLS media playback on android Exoplayer?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using the following code but I get a buffer window of 30s. It produces latency, I want the media to be completely live without the 30s window. 
Here is the code:

```
renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(getApplicationContext());
        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);
        DefaultAllocator allocator=new DefaultAllocator(true,DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
        loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();


        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector, loadControl);
        player.addListener(this);

        dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getApplicationContext(), "ExoplayerDemo");

        if(live){
            Uri urilive=Uri.parse("http://35.200.250.45:1935/live/-LOWyXJ-OHQVa5U6OwVb/playlist.m3u8");

            HlsMediaSource mediaSourcelive= new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).setAllowChunklessPreparation(true).createMediaSource(urilive);

            player.prepare(mediaSourcelive);
```

Comment: What's your stream's segment length? Is it 10 seconds?